# Parse Changing Text in HTML tag Beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to strip out the numbers and the dates from a chart on Zillow.
The url is: https://www.zillow.com/austin-tx/home-values/

The area in the html I'm working with is:

```
<ul class="legend-entries" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1607476788112_1009">
            <li class="legend-value">Oct 2021</li>
            <li class="legend-entry legend-entry-0" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1607476788112_1330">Austin $464K</li>
<li class="hide legend-entry legend-entry-1"></li>
<li class="hide legend-entry legend-entry-2"></li>
<li class="hide legend-entry legend-entry-3"></li>
<li class="hide legend-entry legend-entry-4"></li>
<li class="hide legend-entry legend-entry-5"></li>
<li class="hide legend-entry legend-entry-6"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to parse out the `legend-value` (Oct 2021) and the `legend-entry` ($464K) text. However, when you mouse over the points on the chart (where this data exists on the page), the values in the html change whenever you move the mouse.

Here's my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

all_data = []

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/austin-tx/home-values/'
r = s.get(url, headers=req_headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#soup.find (class_= 'legend-entries')

for ul in soup.find_all('ul'):
    lis=ul.find_all('li')
    for elem in lis:
        all_data.append(elem.text.strip())
```

I feel like this should work, but it returns nothing. The hashed line in my code will return the `legend-entries` tag at least. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: That was generated by javascript.What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That graph comes from an API call. You can fetch that and rebuild the data.

Here's how:

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
api_url = "https://www.zillow.com/ajax/homevalues/data/timeseries.json?r=10221&m=zhvi_plus_forecast&dt=111"
graph = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()
time_ = graph["10221;zhvi_plus_forecast;111"]["data"]
for moment in time_:
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(moment["x"] // 1000).date()
    value = moment["y"]
    print(f"{date} - ${value}")
```

Output:

```
2010-12-31 - $224771
2011-01-31 - $224297
2011-02-28 - $223623
2011-03-31 - $223053
2011-04-30 - $222571
2011-05-31 - $221931
2011-06-30 - $221322
2011-07-31 - $220837
2011-08-31 - $221413
2011-09-30 - $222088
2011-10-31 - $222520
2011-11-30 - $222665
2011-12-31 - $222788
2012-01-31 - $223433
2012-02-29 - $224288
2012-03-31 - $225461
and so on ...
```

Or, you can plot that and have your own graph (who says you can't, right?).

```
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
api_url = "https://www.zillow.com/ajax/homevalues/data/timeseries.json?r=10221&m=zhvi_plus_forecast&dt=111"
graph = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(graph["10221;zhvi_plus_forecast;111"]["data"])
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(df['x'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x // 1000).date()), df['y'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is Great thank you! The only thing I'm wondering is how do you know what the api tag is in that html?

Comment: I didn't even look at the HTML. I found the API endpoint in Developer Tool -> Network -> XHR.

Comment: can you help me a little bit further - what am I looking for within that XHR tab? Trying to do some research on this right now, but it seems like a lot to take in.

Comment: You're basically looking at you browser's traffic and what you want to look for is a request that carries the data for that graph, because, if you turn JavaScript off, that graph ain't there. So it has to be "rendered" dynamically from some other structure. That structure is a JSON object that comes back along with this request - https://imgur.com/a/jfi9Zkh

Comment: Ahhh got it. and found it. So if this is the url: https://www.zillow.com/ajax/homevalues/data/timeseries.json?r=10221&m=zhvi_plus_forecast&dt=1 ---- why did you write the string like this "10221;zhvi_plus_forecast;111" with ";" rather than the &m and &dt??

Comment: Because the API understands those `&` but the `10221;zhvi_plus_forecast;111` is a key in that JSON object you get back as the response. Then, I can access the `data` list and plot the graph. Magic! :D